# How can I configure PyCharm to resolve references to custom functions embedded in the Python global namespace?

Tags: pycharm

I am working with an enterprise software package that uses Python as an embedded scripting language. This software package puts its custom functions in Python's global namespace before it runs Python scripts.

For example, say the enterprise software package makes available a function called "some_enterprise_function". In a script, you can use `some_enterprise_function()` without adding any import statements, even though "some_enterprise_function" isn't used in standard Python.

I want to edit these scripts in PyCharm, but every time I use a custom function, PyCharm underlines the function in red and gives an error like "Unresolved reference 'some_enterprise_function'".

Some of the custom functions are defined in Python modules in the enterprise software package directory tree. This means it is possible to do hacks like this in the Python source files to get rid of the unresolved reference errors:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/path/to/enterprise/software/module")
from enterprise_software_module import *

some_enterprise_function()
```

However, I want PyCharm to be able to resolve references to these functions without altering my source files. Is there a way of configuring PyCharm to do this?